# GWT Compile too slow and freeze PC

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am newbie with GWT and need some help with this technology.

I have a JDK 1.6 +  GWT 2.4 + Maven project with this plugin configuration:

```
    <build>
    <finalName>appname</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <localWorkers>1</localWorkers>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xms5120m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096M</extraJvmArgs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I try to compile the project with the command "mvn gwt:compile":

- It spend 4GB of Ram.
- It generates a 2.7GB file called "gwtXXXXXbyte-cache" on TEMP Dir.
- Use a lot of CPU (Until my pc freeze sometimes).
- After a hour, the java process hang and stop to work.

Probably i am doing something bad, but after spend three days reading documentation and searching over internet, I don't know what.

I think is a lot of resources and time for compile, my PC have 8GB RAM and Intel i5 CPU.

Anybody can help me?

Edit 1:

I have try with this configuration:

```
<build>
        <finalName>webcls</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xms2048M -Xmx5120M -Xss1024k -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts</extraJvmArgs>
                    <server>true</server>
                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                    <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                    <localWorkers>2</localWorkers>
                    <module>it.reply.Login</module>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And I can compile without memory error, but it take 5 hours to compile!

Comment: Your computer may have too little memory (swap + ram).

Comment: I have 8GB RAM and 8GB Swap file.

Comment: That is a lot of permgen space - are you sure you need that much? Also, it might be better to reduce your -Xmx slightly, to only what you have available. This will force GC to run, and avoid trying to use swap which will be far slower.

Comment: I try with less Permgen, I can compile but takes 5 hours

Comment: How big is your codebase? We compile 500k lines of code in less than 15 minutes; with most of the browsers enabled and multiple languages.

Comment: More or less 600K lines of code

Comment: Try removing the extraJVM args and see what happens.

Comment: I tried first without the extra arguments

Comment: Ok, I have reconfigured the project to ANT, with the same GWT parameters the compile time downs from 5 to 3 hours. I have buy a new PC, with an SSD and better processor and the time downs now to 1 hour. I have waiting for a extra 8GB Ram module for have 16GB Ram and see the results.